# Dropdownlist databinding is not working correctly in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to data bind a `<select>` tag using `AngularJS`.

**Script**

```
$scope.customerrouters = [];

$http.post("/Customer/GetCustomerRouterList").success(function (data) {

    $scope.customerrouters = data;

});

$scope.selectedrouters = null;
```

**Html**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="r as r.Name for r in customerrouters" ng-model="selectedrouters">
   <option value="">-- Select --</option>
</select>
```

The problem is that the dorpdownlist renders like in the image below:

[image]

Rendered html

[image]

How can I get the elements to appear?

Comment: what data u r getting,, can u show?

Comment: Paste your `customerrouters` value in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have problem in listing the elements in dropdown. Here is the working Link
[Working](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lj0p3wig9JfOM0UkpDrd?p=preview)

This is my body tag :

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="text" />
   <select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="option.name for option in options">
   </select>
   {{ selectedOption.value }}
</body>
```

and this is my controller :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.options = [{
       name: 'a',
       value: 'something-cool-value'
    }, {
       name: 'b',
       value: 'something-else-value'
}];
```

Here, i have a json data and with the help of the controller `MainCtrl`, i am listing it in dropdown and by changing the value in dropdown, the text will be changed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable answer :)